# Can we get correct (or full) stack dump always for crash issues

Tags: c, debugging, embedded-linux, stack-trace, callstack

Many times we don't get correct or complete stack dump during crash. My question is in what all cases we can see this to happen. 
Probably it can be because of the function call stack getting corrupted. But How such corruption happens.

My 2nd question is how do we debug such an issue and what approach we can take to find the root cause for the crash.

I understand my questions may not have an exact answer but I would like to know your thoughts.

Thank You...

Comment: Your questions are multiple and unclear, and might be off-topic here because unrelated to any source code.

Answer (score 1):

It is operating system and platform (i.e. processor) specific.

The best way is to use a debugger to find such issues (perhaps a remote one, learn about [`gdbserver`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Server.html))

I would suggest to debug most of your code on a desktop Linux system (because you have lots of useful tools: [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), `gcc -fsanitize=address`, `gdb`, etc...)

Of course, the [call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) can be corrupted to the point of being unusable. Try to `memset` the stack segment, then return from the function doing that (no matter what tool or trick you would use, the stack is then desperately corrupted on most platforms)!

You might be interested by [GNU glibc `backtrace` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Backtraces.html), [GCC `__builtin_return_address`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html), [libbbacktrace by Ian Taylor in GCC](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/tree/8df488f9949cffec6a6d120562746662ec19c25e/libbacktrace)

You might also enable `core` dumps and analyze them post mortem (perhaps using a cross-debugger). See [core(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html), [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html)